# Replacing Insulating blanket around oven (patching grease spill)

Tags: insulation, oven, stove, range

[image: Gas Range]

I accidentally spilled some oil on the stove which seeped down below the top.  The oil is now in the insulating blanket that surrounds the oven and caught fire while a burner was on.  Can I buy new insulating material, cut out this patch and replace it?  Any help appreciated.

edit:  can I use this product to patch it?
[https://www.amazon.com/Ceramic-Insulation-Ceramics-CM-Ceramics-Instructions/dp/B015GD0QCW/ref=pd_cp_60_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=G3MA4QEVGWZ0CFCYCDKX](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015GD0QCW)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to find the right material, as this is certainly high-temperature insulation and you don't want to have a new fire. Where to find that insulation is off-topic here, but once it's in hand it doesn't look like replacing that small section will be too bad a job (certainly less work than you've already put in).

Comment: Thanks, if you have expertise, can you verify that the link I posted would be an appropriate material?

Comment: I don't have expertise (aside being an engineer), but that does look good.